# Webcasts 2016 - ¿cómo y por qué? -- ¡Fechas!

Tags: discusión, webcast

**Enlaces a los Webcasts del 2016:**

---

[**Episodio 1** - *¿Qué fue lo que te impulso hacia el desarrollamiento y el código? ¿Que se necesita para ser exitoso en esta carrera?* Feb 2016](http://bit.ly/1T6p06w)

[**Episodio 2** - *Cosas que deseas haber aprendido sobre el desarrollo que tuviste que aprender después de varios dolores de cabeza.* - Mar 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zd-YYaEYdg4)

[**Episodio 3** - *Trabajo desde casa, mitos y realidades.* - Abril 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8C1soDvDYno)

[**Episodio 4** - *El desarrollo de videojuegos - Parte 1.* - Mayo 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdISxT1IZjk)

[**Episodio 5** - *El desarrollo de videojuegos - Parte 2.* - Junio 2016](https://youtu.be/6Fu0gJFUKw4)

[**Episodio 6** - *Técnicas de estudio en la programación.* -  Julio 2016](https://youtu.be/cUzd8itXfOk)

[**Episodio 7** - *Entrevista con Gabe Koscky, CM del sitio portugués.* - Agosto 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CdfxSFCkCQ)

[**Episodio 8** - *Entrevista con Nicolas Chabanovsky, CM del sitio ruso.* - Septiembre 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKt6MJv8UPs)

[**Episodio 9** - *SOes sigue creciendo ¿ahora qué? Entrevista con los moderadores del sitio.* - Octubre 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V97G1rxAaW4)

*Noviembre 2016 - Descanso *

[**Episodio 10** - *Episodio 10: Buenas prácticas al momento de codificar o desarrollar una aplicación.* - Diciembre 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1WT1xk48Ng)

¡Espero que nos puedan acompañar!

---

Una de las cosas que ayudan a una comunidad a sentirse como una comunidad real es la interacción entre los miembros.  Las interacciones a la que me refiero son las que pueden ser consideradas fuera de tema.  Imaginen tres o cuatro trabajadores en una empresa.  Estos se ven a diario y platican sobre todo tipo de tema sobre su trabajo.  Se conocen poco a poco pero no se pueden considerar amigos hasta que no empiezen a tratar temas fuera del trabajo.  Por ejemplo, que comida les gusta, que actividades les gusta realizar los fines de semana, y otras cosas por el estilo.  De igual forma, nuestra comunidad se platica entre si, pero falta un lugar para poder ir al mas allá.

Por ahora, tenemos una forma de cultivar interacciones mas profundas - [**el chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol). Por cierto, si no has visitado el chat, ¡te invitamos!

Pienso que el chat no es suficiente.  Por este motivo, he pensado empezar una serie de webcasts por Google Hangouts donde podamos platicar sobre otros temas relacionados a nuestro oficio - el desarrollamiento y el uso de código para crear aplicaciones para el mundo de la computación.  Me gustaría tener un webcast al mes y dar una fecha donde puedan ustedes verlo en vivo.

### El formato

El plan es simple - invitar a 2 o 3 panelistas de nuestra comunidad para tratar un tema especifico.  Dentro del tiempo haremos preguntas, discutiremos experiencias, y nos mostraríamos cara a cara para podernos ir conociendo.  Para mí, el saber con quien hablo es muy importante para poder crear un relación mas real. La idea es esta, permitir que la comunidad vea a los miembros como gente real y escucharlos hablar sobre temas que nos interesan.

Me encantaría tener una manera de crear esto en vivo pero por motivos financieros, no sera posible.  La mejor opción entonces es de hacer un webcast en vivo.

### Los temas

Tengo ya unos temas en mente pero me gustaría oír sus sugerencias.  Después de todo, el webcast es para ustedes.

Esperen el primer webcast a medias de febrero.  Estoy todavía en proceso de finalizar con nuestros primeros panelistas.  Recuerden que todos tienen una oportunidad de ser panelistas si les interesa - quiero que la comunidad se vaya conociendo mas y mas.

Comment: "pero falta un lugar para poder ir **al mas allá**." - Espero no tener que ir al más allá pronto :S

Comment: ...puede ser en cuestión a la metafísica, siendo que estamos en Meta, jeje.

Comment: Sería un buen nombre para webcast... "El más allá" :D

Comment: me apunto! ya que se hablan de temas metafísicos, podríamos hablar sobre la ley de la atracción en nuestras vidas, el poder de los pensamientos, las palabras y las acciones. Como mejorar nuestras vidas, mentalizarnos y atraer lo que buscamos. Por otro lado, quizás seria bueno hablar sobre como ser buenos programadores, tecnologías actuales y las que se vienen, herramientas, tips, compartir experiencias como debuggers y como hacer uso de un pensamiento diferente para solucionar problemas.

Comment: Ya estaba pensando si se haría algo como esto, y pues acá esta, Éxitos!!!!

Comment: "El más allá" es el lugar al que van los datos de una pila desbordada. Todo cuadra.

Comment: Like! Perdón, +1. Juan, la idea está genial

Comment: Cool, quedo atento.

Comment: Esto nunca lo he visto en el SOinglés. Me prepararé unas palomitas...

Comment: Por las expresiones que usas al escribir, deduzco que eres de Latinoamérica así que asumo que este webcast sería en horario de allí, lo que nos deja a los desarrolladores del otro lado del charco en un horario incómodo para asisitir :(

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Si, estoy al otro lado del charco.  Entiendo que los horarios no serán convenientes a todos pero trataremos de escoger un tiempo en donde podamos unirnos que sea flexible para todos.  Recuerda que los webcasts serán grabados así que se podrán ver en otra ocasión mas conveniente para los que no puedan verlos en vivo.

Comment: Les parece si optamos por utilizar una zona horaria española de noche: 7pm-8pm, así todo Latinoamérica estaría despierta, aquí el mapa de las zonas horarias a nivel mundial: http://www.worldtimezone.com/ Opino que sea un fin de semana para que la mayoría pueda participar. Webcasts - ¿Qué dicen? ¿Se apuntan a esta propuesta de horario?

Comment: @fredyfx Me gusta la idea pero necesito tomar en cuenta los horarios de los panelistas también.  Si se puede a esas horas, lo hacemos, si no, tendremos que modificar el horario un poco.

Comment: Buena voz @JuanM! y hay panelistas? Seria bonito un compartir entre diferentes experiencias sobre los stack de desarrollo, me gustaría aportar un granito de arena con lo que conozco sobre ASP.net MVC + JavaScript, herramientas y el buen debugging. Saludos

Comment: @fredyfx mándame un correo electrónico para darte unos detalles (mi correo esta en mi cuenta)

Comment: @JuanM estaría muy bien tener un horario que fuese adecuado para todos los hispanohablantes; la propuesta de fredyfx de hacerlo en fin de semana también es buena idea. No se cuántos habrán interesados en C++ pero a mi me encantaría ofrecerme como panelista de dicho lenguaje.

Comment: No es mála idea, no obstante me parece fuera del alcance de stackoverflow a día de hoy. Cómo experimento quizás pueda funcionar. Auqnue quizás sería mas interseante crear un grupo de meetup asociado stackoverflow_es. Así toda la gestión de asistentes y demás se podría llevar a acabo ahí...

Comment: @gavioto20 a eso vamos...poco a poco ;)

Comment: No olvidar editar/actualizar esta entrada (pregunta) agregando el enlace a la grabación del primer Webcast [Episodio 1](https://youtu.be/k0H_6mWsnJ8).

Comment: y el enlace? venga, vamos! compartan por favor :)

Comment: @fredyfx listo - el post ha sido actualizado :)

Comment: perfecto! Cuál sera el siguiente tema?

Comment: @fredyfx ya esta :)

Comment: vale! gracias y a seguir con los webcasts!

Comment: Ahora ¿quien va a salir al ring para el 3° round?

Comment: Excelente iniciativa, lastima que apenas hoy pude estar al tanto por lo que me ha sido imposible seguir los eventos anteriores :) quedo atento al siguiente.

Comment: se acaba setiembre, habrá WebCast este mes?

Comment: Por supuesto qué sí . Solo falta finalizar con los panelistas.

Comment: Este mes habrá webcast?? También falta actualizar esta publicación con el video del webcast N° 8 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKt6MJv8UPs

Comment: @JuanPinzón Buen ojo.... (1) actualizo esta publicación de inmediato  (2) estoy planeando el webcast de octubre pero falta confirmar con los panelistas.  Aviso aquí luego.

Comment: Genial @JuanM, estaré pendiente del nuevo webcast.

Comment: @JuanM, estoy ahora viendo el capítulo 9, apenas en el minuto 8, me encanta ver esto en movimiento. Gracias por tanto esfuerzo y tanto entusiasmo, lamento no poder llevarles el ritmo, pero así es la vida, algún día tendré el tiempo para hacerlo! :) Un abrazo!

Comment: @jachguate ¡¡Saludos hombre!! Que bueno el verte por aquí. Se aprecian tus palabras. Un fuerte saludo :)

Comment: @JuanM ¿Webcasts 2017? ¿Editas el hilo o creas uno nuevo?

Answer (score 17):

Propongo el siguiente tema:

### Trabajo desde casa, Mitos y realidades.

Conocer la experiencia de las personas que trabajan desde casa, Y lecciones aprendidas.

Answer (score 13):

Propongo el siguiente tema:

### Cosas que deseas haber aprendido sobre el desarrollo que tuviste que aprender después de varios dolores de cabeza.

Pienso que se pueden dar consejos valiosos aquí, especialmente para los que apenas empiezan en esta carrera.

Answer (score 12):

Propongo el siguiente tema:

## Tips para obtener el trabajo que quieres. Cómo debes prepararte, la educación necesaria, networking, etc.

Seria un tema interesante donde podremos escuchar las experiencias de otros y la manera en que superaron sus obstáculos.

Comment: Este tema es interesante :)

Comment: me apunto a este tema, en lo personal, mi CV ha tenido una evolución de unas 80 ediciones aprox. (8 grandes cambios en temas de diseño) y en cada versión, pequeños ajustes como formatos y contenido actualizado. Saludos!

Comment: me encantaría participar de este webcast, me sorprendí consiguiendo un trabajo genial y creo que tengo algunas cosas para compartir :)

Answer (score 10):

#### Propongo el siguiente tema:

### [Internet of Things (IoT)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_de_las_cosas) o Internet de las cosas:

Este es un sector que esta produciendo muchos proyectos.

Comment: excelente tema - me gusta :)

Answer (score 10):

### Técnicas de estudio en la programación

Referido a la manera de aprender una nueva tecnología, como iniciar en ella, herramientas, tips, compartir experiencias de cómo lograron instalarse el compilador en el C:\erebro, hacer un debugging con la mirada (sí es posible!) detalles así que motiven al público a expandirse.

Como saben, la programación no es un curso que se lleva y ahí queda, el inicio es muy importante porque vas construyendo las bases y fundamentos de algo que ni te imaginas que podrás hacer en un futuro. El punto es cómo llegar a dominar X tecnología partiendo desde cero o basado en alguna otra tecnología.

Un gran docente de la universidad siempre dice que los fundamentos son más importantes que las tecnologías que salen al mercado porque las tecnologías cambian constantemente pero los fundamentos se mantienen.

Answer (score 9):

Propongo el siguiente tema:

## Gestión de entornos de desarrollo

Docker, Vagrant, etc... es cada vez más necesario trabajar simultáneamente con distintas tecnologías.

Answer (score 9):

Propongo el tema:

## Las mujeres en la industria del software

- Vivencias de la escuela
- ¿Es más difícil encontrar trabajo siendo mujer?
- Que les dirías para motivar a las nuevas desarrolladores
- ¿Cómo son los equipos de trabajo donde predominan los hombres?

Comment: Muy interesante este tema.

Comment: Excelente tema, ahora solo necesitamos tener a algunas panelistas....a buscar, ¡vamos!

Comment: Creo que ha llegado la hora que @Elenasys se anime

Answer (score 8):

Propongo el siguiente tema:

### Mini [TED Talks](https://www.ted.com/talks)- comparte un tema especial para ti en 15 minutos.

Los temas tendrán demostraciones, videos, fotos o gráficas para el público.  Los panelistas serán miembros de nuestra comunidad.

Comment: Otro formato interesante de presentación puede ser [PechaKucha 20x20](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/PechaKucha).

Comment: Me parece que es una gran idea

Answer (score 7):

## La piratería de software

- ¿Cuando en la universidad necesitas algo forzosamente para una clase pero cuesta mucho $$$$?
- ¿Te quitas oportunidades de trabajo cuando no pagas por un software?
- ¿Recomiendas a tus amigos una alternativa libre?
- ¿Llegue a un nuevo trabajo y todo su software es pirata que hago?

Answer (score 6):

Propongo el siguiente tema:

### ¡Desarrollo de videojuegos!

Si puedo encontrar a panelistas que nos platiquen sobre sus logros o sus proyectos actuales, me convertiría de nuevo en un niño con monedas para las maquinitas.

[image: jugando a las maquinitas]

Comment: Si, si, si, si, si!

Comment: @jasilva Cuando siga este tema, te invito para ser panelista. :)

Comment: con muchisimo gusto :D

Comment: :) Esto estaría genial!

Answer (score 6):

### Que son los bots?

Propongo el tema de que alguien pueda desarrollar un webcast sobre este tema, los puntos serian:

1. Que son, como y cuando nacieron.
2. Como desarrollar un bot.
3. Sobre que lenguajes se puede trabajar.

Y de mas cosas que se me escapan al no conocer el tema

[image: Bots]

Comment: @JuanM Tengo un panelista de para esto, un compañero de trabajo: http://stackoverflow.com/users/90081/ezequiel-jadib

Comment: Yo he trabajado con bots si desean puedo ser panelista :)

Comment: @Wilfredo ok, esperemos a ver que dice juan

Answer (score 6):

## Entrevistas de trabajo para puestos de programación/desarrollo

1. Qué conceptos se suelen preguntar y cuáles deberían dominarse
2. Estructura de una entrevista
3. Diferencias entre países y/o compañías
4. Preguntas raras o divertidas que les hayan hecho a los panelistas

Answer (score 5):

Basado en una discusión en el chat:

## OpenSource / Comercial ¿Que es mejor para un desarrollador?

- Opiniones personales sobre el desarrollo Comercial o Libre.
- Experiencia en desarrollos Libres.
- Experiencia en desarrollos comerciales.
- ¿Cómo conseguir dinero con desarrollo Libre?

Answer (score 4):

## Desarrollador Frontend vs Desarrollador Backend vs Desarrollador Fullstack. ¿Cual sería la mejor opción?

La idea es conocer cual sería la mejor opción actualmente, si tener un trabajo especializado o conocer de todo.

Answer (score 4):

**Calidad del software y/o pruebas del software**

Los humanos cometemos errores. Los humanos realizan software, luego el software puede tener errores. Propongo dedicar un Webcast al aseguramiento en la calidad del software o sobre la importancia, técnicas y estado del arte de las pruebas de software en los productos implementados.

Answer (score 4):

## Buenas prácticas al momento de codificar o desarrollar una aplicación.

Con sub-temas relacionados con:

- Patrones de diseño.
- Seguridad en el código (evitar inyección sql, css, entre otros).
- Como escribir código legible y mantenible.
- Entornos para programar(Windows, Linux, MAC)

Answer (score 3):

Basado en la discusion en el chat, propongo:

## ¿Como usar el marketing / Cominuty Manager / Otras herramientas para vender o promocionar mi Producto / software?

La idea es conocer cuales pueden ser las estrategias a nivel de las redes sociales, para promocionar mi producto.

Comment: las redes sociales

Comment: @jasilva Listo modificado.

Answer (score 3):

## Ergonomia en la programación

- La postura correcta para programar
- Ejercicios de relajación
- Laptop en la cama. ¿Es lo mejor?
- ¿Has probado el **stand working**?
- ¿El túnel carpiano, mito o realidad?

Answer (score 3):

Conversando con [@Lamak](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/26/lamak) y [@Mariano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano) en la sala de chat, salió la idea de hacer webcasts sobre "Inteligencia de Negocios", conocido también como "Business Intelligence". Sé que no tiene que ver mucho con la programación, sin embargo, miremos de esta manera: Webcasts sobre temas que utilicemos profesionalmente donde compartamos una mezcla de teoría y experiencias vividas.

Siento que eso podría darnos una mano a seguir expandiendo nuestra comunidad a nivel hispanoamérica. ¿Se imaginan que la hermandad de SOes publique una serie de webcasts de diversas tecnologías con el apoyo de cada uno que anda leyendo este mensaje? Dar lo mejor de uno para hacer una mejor comunidad, ¿Quién se apunta?

Comment: Yo me apunto. Afortunadamente, los útlimos años he tenido oportunidad de trabajar con diferentes culturas y he tenido experiencias tanto muy buenas como muy malas en diferentes aspectos de áreas de TI y con gusto me gustaría expresar mi experiencia. Saludos!