# Implementar banners para promocionar los Web Cast y otros eventos

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, webcast

Esta propuesta surge por el éxito del primer [Web Cast](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419), por el capitulo #2 a fines de esta semana y por la reciente propuesta de [Mentoría y equipos de aprendizaje grupal](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/496) la cual espero prospere por que es una gran idea.

Ya se que esta la sección Destacados en Meta, pero eso esta bien para usuarios mas experimentados. Por ello...

¿Seria posible implementar "banners" como el que aparece a los usuarios anónimos y a los que tienen menos de 200 puntos de reputación en cualquier sitio Graduado?

Estos banners deberían, justamente, promocionar todos estos eventos, de forma que los usuarios nuevos estén bien al tanto de todas estas movidas, cuando son y como acceder a ellas.

Con unos banners apropiados -que podrían ser preparados por nosotros mismos- podemos aumentar la audiencia y empujar la comunidad a hacerse mas conocida y por que no atraer mas expertos.

A propósito, me ofrezco para colaborar con este trabajo, no soy un artista consumado, pero me defiendo bien con Inkscape.

Me refiero a esto.... solo que ahí estarían los banners confeccionados para tales fines.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que buena idea, no se si por el sitio haya diseñadores, yo se un poco de inkscape y de otros libres, +1

Comment: @jasilva no se viste en el chat pero el [84.5% del trafico](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gzmqi.png) esta entrando desde internet. Con algo así podríamos llenar el estadio con los Web Cast.

Answer (score 5):

### Webcasts StackOverflow en Español

[image: WebCast]

---

SVG original Inkscape

https://github.com/jaksilva/soes/blob/master/img/soes-webcast.svg

Comment: ¡me gusta el concepto!

Comment: jajaja ... asombroso!

Comment: Para ser programador, jeje, si alguien quiere editarlo es **totalmente bienvenido**, iba a dejar el codigo en la respuesta pero solo admite 30000 caracteres  y el svg lo superaba por unos miles XD

Comment: me encanta la imagen! @jasilva te hiciste un golazo de media cancha y encima de cabeza!

Comment: @fredyfx Muchas gracias, solo espero que Joel no me demande por uso de la marca XD

Comment: de nada @jasilva por cierto si quieres compartir el código, un pastebin le va bien!

Comment: Buenaaaaaaaaaaaaa!