# ¿Se debería eliminar la etiqueta [latex]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Hace poco publiqué en SOes una pregunta con la etiqueta de latex, pues desconocía que existe texschange (aunque solamente en inglés), sin embargo creo que sería mejor quemar esta etiqueta de una vez por lo siguientes motivos:

1. Al buscar esa etiqueta se ve que en los últimos años se ha utilizado muy pocas veces
2. Muchas veces al preguntar con esa etiqueta te dirigen a una pregunta similar en el sitio de texschange
3. Al haber un sitio específico para latex esta etiqueta debería quedar obsoleta
4. He visto que algunas preguntas se tardan mucho en contestar un ejemplo [es esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/438294/problema-con-el-estilo-de-citas-especifico-csl-apa-csl-pero-tengo-el-mismo-r), en mi caso, al necesitar una respuesta urgente tuve que iniciar una recompensa para obtener una respuesta siendo una pregunta de principiantes.

Answer (score 7):

La cantidad de preguntas sobre una etiqueta no son motivo suficiente para eliminar una etiqueta. Actualmente la etiqueta tiene 59 preguntas, tiene orientación de uso y se usa en los momentos correctos.

Respondo punto por punto a tus puntos:

1. La cantidad de veces que se use por año no tiene nada que ver con la etiqueta. También puede quedar por motivos históricos.
2. Bien podrían traducir la respuesta y ponerla aquí.
3. Si hiciéramos eso, también deberíamos eliminar wordpress, todas las de bases de datos, todas las de *nix, y la lista podría ser bastante larga.
4. Esto no tiene nada que ver con que la etiqueta exista o no. Tu urgencia no es un problema de la comunidad en si. Si hay un sitio dedicado es muy probable que encuentres información técnica mas dedicada y mas rápido. Sin embargo, no todos pueden ir a los sitios en otros idiomas, y muchas preguntas son perfectamente validas acá.

Dicho todo esto, yo estoy en contra de siquiera tocar esa etiqueta.

Comment: ¿Y cómo surge una comunidad en otro idioma?

Por ejemplo un texschange en español

Comment: @EduardoJiménez Todas las nuevas comunidades nacen en el area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

En mi opinion, los motivos no son concretos para poder eliminarla

1. El hecho de que se utilice pocas veces no quiere decir que nunca se dejará de utilizar, por lo que habra usuarios preguntando con esa etiqueta
2. Hay etiquetas como [woocommerce](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce), [wordpress](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) o [unity](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) que se utilizan en el sitio aunque existan foros exclusivos para realizar preguntas con esos temas
3. Como ya te dijo [@gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) tu urgencia no es problema de la comunidad. Existen preguntas que a veces nunca son contestadas y por el hecho de ser asi, no significa que se deban eliminar las etiquetas asociadas a ellas

Answer (score -3):

Yo no estoy a favor ni en contra de la eliminación de la etiqueta pero pienso que es hora y urge delimitar el *"borde de la pila"*, es decir, señalar que tipo de tecnologías van a ser abarcadas y que no.

Para mi quizas en un inicio ha sido aceptado muchos temas en el sitio debido a:

- Poca moderación por parte de la comunidad.
- Habia subcomunidades dentro de SOes que aceptaban y respondias ese tipo de tecnologías, etc.

En SOen se comenzo aceptando muchas tecnologías pero despues nos dimos cuenta que no era adecuado por lo que para ello se tomo ciertas medidas:

- Quemar las etiquetas que estan fuera del alcance del sitio.
- Las publicaciones que estan fueran de tema pero tienen alta puntuación se quedan bloqueadas por motivos históricos por lo que ya no pueden responderse ni modificarlas.
- Delimitar cuando una etiqueta que tiene preguntas que pueden estar dentro del alcance del sitio y cuando no, etc.

Eso ayuda a la moderación ya que es frustrante ver temas que no tienen que ver con programación como la configuración de sistemas operativos. Muchos señalan que el tema es valido porque son herramientas de los programadores usan pero con ese mismo argumento tambien serian validos preguntas como "¿Qué tipo de PC debe usar un programador?", etc. En SOen se pueden responder preguntas sobre las herramientas pero deben tener una relación muy estrecha como por ejemplo las IDEs.

Comment: cuando actualizamos el recorrido, creo que delimitamos esas cosas como las preguntas sobre sistemas operativos. Ahora, una cosa es que haya comunidades en el mismo idioma que cubran esas bases (por eso en SOen se pueden eliminar etiquetas y migrar las preguntas). Aca, no hay comunidades en el mismo idioma que cubran algunas cosas...

Comment: @gbianchi Que existan las otras comunidades no hicieron que SO eliminara esas subcomunidades sino que esas tecnologias estan fueran de tema pero inicialmente se toleraron.

Comment: Y se crearon otras comunidades que ya cumplen en contestar ese tipo de preguntas. No se eliminan tecnologias por obsoletas.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿quién dijo que se eliminan las tecnologías? eso es ilogico. Lo que se hace es quemas esas etiquetas, señalar en que casos son válidas o señalar claramente que esa etiqueta no es válida

Comment: quemar la etiqueta es hacer que desaparezca y no se pueda preguntar mas... por lo tanto, estas eliminando la misma para busquedas. Y es mas, no estas permitiendo preguntar mas sobre esas cosas.

Comment: @gbianchi y ese es el objetivo, si ya se sabe que una tecnología en si no es válida para el sitio entonces ¿por qué permitir que el usuario utilice esa etiqueta? Con tus argumentos estas señalando que cualquier pregunta que se puede hacer en alguna comunidad de SE entonces es valida para SO, con esa lógica las preguntas de matemática, de idiomas, de diseño de base de datos, de ingeniería de SW, de revision de código, etc. En mi mente en SO resolvemos preguntas muy delimitadas y no intentamos cubrir todas las tecnologías porque nos desviamos del camino.

Comment: Redefino. Cuando se quema la etiqueta se elimina pero permite volver a aparecer. Hay que ponerla en la lista negra para que no vuelva a aparecer. Ahora, volviendo a lo otro. nunca dije que se puede preguntar cualquier cosa. El ambito del sitio esta definido y hace poco lo volvimos a definir al ajustar lo que se lee en el recorrido. SO quemo y quito cosas, porque habia otros sitios que ya cubrian esas cosas, no porque la tecnologia estuviera deprecada. Vos decis que si voy y hago una pregunta sobre clipper o cobol, me van a cerrar la pregunta?

Comment: dejame entender tu punto de vista. Como existe un sitio de wordpress, no deberiamos aceptar preguntas sobre programacion en php para wordpress?

Comment: Voy a responder tus comentarios por partes: 1)Yo no hablo sobre tecnología antigua o nueva, ¿como defines que algo es viejo? ¿como defines que cierta tecnología es obsoleta? Muchos bancos aun usan esa tecnología "obsoleta".

Comment: ok de acuerdo. Pero entonces vuelvo a mi comentario anterior. Aceptamos o no preguntas sobre wordpress?

Comment: 2) Sobre lo de wordpress, si la preguntas es sobre programación entonces si es valida pero si es sobre configuración o pedido plugins entonces no.

Comment: [cont.] Justamente esas tecnologías estan al borde donde son válidas en varios sitios, el mismo tema lo tiene "excel" o "bash".

Comment: las segundas se cierran de plano.. no se pueden pedir librerias. segun tu punto de vista, entonces, las preguntas de latex no deberian existir aca porque: A- existe ya una comunidad sobre eso (aunque sea en otro idioma) o B- No son sobre programacion?

Comment: [cont.] y eso es lo que señala la etiqueta en el sitio en ingles: *This tag is for programming-specific questions about the WordPress content management system. Off-topic questions include those about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, server configuration, etc. These are best asked on the dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).*

Comment: 3) Mi punto no tiene nada que ver que existan o no comunidades que lo cubran, las reglas del sitio no se pueden definir si ya existe un sitio que lo cubra. Asi que si se simplifica mucho la cosa la que acerca a mi posición es la B.

Comment: ok. si no son sobre programacion es valido el punto. desconozco en profundidad si latex es un lenguaje per se o no...

Comment: @gbianchi Exacto, justamente en este tipo de discusion permito no dar mi posición porque no soy experto y eso lo señale en mi post: *"Yo no estoy a favor ni en contra de la eliminación de la etiqueta"*. Tengo el derecho a opinar pero reconozco mi limitación por lo que espero que los expertos den su punto de vista pero en tu respuesta no encontre ello por lo que señalo mi posición sobre la politica del manejo de tecnologías en el sitio que va mucho más alla de la etiqueta latex

Comment: Mi respuesta es sobre si corresponde o no quemar la etiqueta desde un punto de vista de uso, basado en lo que dice el usuario. Y el uso de la etiqueta en el sitio.

Comment: @gbianchi es que con tu posición podria en un momento dado un grupo de usuarios crear sus cuentas en SO y podrian preguntar cualquier tema y crear esa etiqueta y entonces por el uso deberian quedarse. Ese es mi argumento. Mi respuesta no solo abarca el punto de vista del AP sino que va más ya que estas publicaciones sirven para dar una visión general del sitio, no solo responder al AP.

Comment: Si es sobre uno de los temas permitidos, que lo impide? No entiendo tu posicion respecto a eso. Toda mi respuesta es basada en el pedido de quemar una etiqueta. En tal caso, abramos una pregunta que sea si corresponden o no las preguntas sobre latex, y en base a eso se decide. Yo conteste si correspondia  o no quemar la etiqueta segun se pide.

Comment: @gbianchi mmm, ¿A qué te refieres con tema permitido? ¿quien define o donde esta definido cuando un tema es permitido? Eso es lo que justamente este pidiendo.

Comment: Los temas definidos y que redefinimos en el recorrido y en como preguntar. Si queres retocar rl ambito de las preguntas sos libre de hacer tu pregunta en meta. Aca se pidio quemar una etiqueta basado en 4 supuestos, y yo di mi punto de vista de pq ninguno de esos supuestos correspondia para quemarla. De vez en cuando quemo, genero sinonimos y uno etiquetas. Y esta, no me parece, y di mi punto de vista como en todas aquellas que no me parecio.

Comment: ya, okay. Pero mi punto de vista es otro.

Comment: claro, pero me parece que tu respuesta no es sobre esta pregunta...

Comment: @gbianchi Eso es tu punto de vista, algunos responden a lo que el AP pregunta que es valido(que tambien cubre lo que el AP pregunta) y que otros queremos ir algo más alla que tambien es válido.

Comment: me parece perfecto que quieras ir mas alla.. pero tu mas alla queda inmerso en una respuesta sobre la cual solo se puede debatir en comentarios... mejor hacer una pregunta respecto a eso....

Comment: @gbianchi ese es tu visión. Mi posicion es que esa etiqueta puede ser quemada si aclaramos que esa tecnología es valida o no para el sitio. Tampoco tu eres quien define cuando algo es o no es un problema de la comunidad, ese comentario parece muy pedante.

Comment: no se como puedo ser pedante, cuando te estoy diciendo que para tener mejor esta discusion, mejor la pongas en una pregunta para que absolutamente todos puedan opinar. ASi entre todos se decide si latex es o no un tema valido en el sitio.

Comment: Si te molesta hacer la pregunta, no te preocupes, yo la hago con todo gusto.

Comment: @gbianchi no sé a que te refieres con molestia solo que para mi lo que señalas en tu respuesta: *Tu urgencia no es un problema de la comunidad en si.* suena pedante.

Comment: No se a que venia eso.. mi respuesta fue en base a lo escrito en la pregunta "...en mi caso, al necesitar una respuesta urgente tuve que iniciar una recompensa para obtener una respuesta siendo una pregunta de principiantes." OP se queja que no recibio respuesta rapido cuando la necesitaba y que por eso tuvo que abrir una recompensa. Entonces por eso esta mi comentario. Que no reciba una respuesta rapida, no es motivo para quemar una etiqueta.

Comment: @gbianchi okay, entonces perdon. No me di cuenta de ello. Pense que el comentario indicaba que su petición no era valida. Ahora recien me doy cuenta de que las enumeraciones en tu respuesta responde a las enumeraciones del AP, quizas debiste ser más explicito en ello señalando que vas a responder cada punto.

Comment: Tambien analizando la publicación del AP veo que es demasiado amplio para su titulo. Quizas un título más adecuado seria: ¿como tramitar o proceder con una pregunta de latex? Lo señalo porque la eliminación solo es una parte de lo que el AP pregunta.

Comment: perfecto, ya aclaro lo de la enumeracion. Ahora se entiende que yo conteste puntualmente lo que se pregunta aca, sin importarme si la etiqueta corresponde o no. si la etiqueta corresponde o no es una pregunta totalmente valida de tratar en meta

Comment: Claro, es obvio. Pero lo que señalo es que el título del AP no cubre todo lo que se señala en la publicación del AP.

Comment: eso, reclamaselo a OP.. yo conteste su publicación completa, no me detuve en el titulo....

Comment: @gbianchi yo no te estoy reclamando nada, solo te estoy señalando mi reflexión sobre lo confuso que es el post del AP

Comment: no no.. por eso puse reclamaselo a OP ;)

Comment: @gbianchi En SO no se debe reclamar nada, quizas dar una sugerencia.

Comment: @eyllanesc Creo que deberias ver esta [pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/500) ya que ahi hay respuestas sobre "Que es programar en SOes"

Comment: @gbianchi se deberia trasladar la conversacion a un chat? Es muy extenso...

Comment: No. En meta no movemos nada a un chat.

Comment: Yo también opino que esta respuesta tiene demasiados comentarios por lo que deberían moverse a un chat. @gbianchi De dónde sale eso de "En meta no  movemos nada a un chat"?

Comment: @Rubén eso es una costumbre de meta de SOen, muchas veces mover el chat involucra señalar que solo lo lean lo que estan discutiendo en vez de que eso lo siga la comunidad.

Comment: @eyllanesc No he visto conversaciones tan largas en Meta de SOen, pero si he visto que se muevan comentarios a chat.

Comment: @Rubén por el contrario, yo he visto discusiones mas largas y nunca lo he visto moverse al chat, al menos en los que comente nunca se movieron al chat. En cambio en el sitio principal la politica es otra.

Comment: @gbianchi mmm aunque sea muy extenso? Si va mas de 100 comentarios...bueno si las reglas es no mover...

Comment: @Rubén varios usuarios se han quejado cuando movimos comentarios al chat desde meta. Por lo tanto, en meta no tocamos los comentarios...

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por la aclaración. Pues ya tienes un usuario quejandose porque no se mueven :)

Comment: @Rubén Te cuento una anecdota: cuando hubo el problema con Monica una de las acciones que molestaron a la comunidad fue que movieran las discusiones que se daban en la secciones de comentarios al chat ya que se siente que es una forma de callar nuestras libertades.

Comment: Coincido con @gbianchi, esta respuesta está fuera de lugar, no responde la pregunta ni tiene relación con las etiquetas de las misma, debería publicarse como una pregunta.

Comment: @Rubén Si no estas deacuerdo con mi respuesta entonces dale un *downvote* pero yo soy consciente de que para mi es una respuesta.

Comment: @Rubén por ahi seria ideal generar una pregunta respecto de los comentarios aqui en meta...

Comment: @gbianchi Podría ser... por lo pronto aquí sólo [he enontrado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta+comentarios) una pregunta con las etiquetas meta y comentarios.