# Webcasts 2017 - ¿cómo y por qué? — ¡Fechas!

Tags: discusión, webcast

[Enlaces a los Webcasts del 2016](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419/webcasts-2016-c%C3%B3mo-y-por-qu%C3%A9-fechas)

---

Bienvenidos todos a la lista de los webcasts para el 2017.  Podrán encontrar los enlaces a los episodios aquí y también al enlace para asistir al evento en vivo del mes.

[**Episodio 11** - *Entrevista con Gervasio Marchand - Desarrollador, Stack Overflow. Enero 2017*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_cJCk4X4c)

[**Episodio 12** - *Discusión sobre C++ con PaperBirdMaster y Eferion. Febrero 2017*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByscoOrkmGw)

[**Episodio 13** - *Discusión sobre C# con FredyFx y Flxtr. Abril 2017*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHDz-sZ-Ql8)

[**Episodio 14** - *Una discusión de APIs con Marco Antonio Sanz y Jorge Baumann. Julio 2017*](https://tinyurl.com/yd48xupf)

[**Episodio 15** -  *Cómo usar Data Science para analizar datos importantes con Gervasio Marchand. Agosto 2017*](http://tinyurl.com/yahkuyc5)

[**Episodio 16** - *¡Una discusión con nuestros moderadores oficiales!*. Septiembre 2017](http://bit.ly/2wGtACf)

¡Espero que nos puedan acompañar!

---

Seguimos con el intento de proporcionarles buenas charlas con los miembros de nuestra comunidad.  Trataremos diferentes temas cada mes y seguiremos buscando otras maneras de comunicarnos para que esto siga siendo de ayuda para todos nosotros.

Los webcasts se graban en vivo y se aceptan las preguntas.  Compartiremos los enlaces de los webcasts para que puedan asistir.  Si por algún motivo no pueden participar en vivo, pueden ver la grabación en nuestro [*canal de YouTube*](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtuOuRfJHaReTPEPf0RTMVg).

Comment: _¡este año SOes explota!_-- la pitonisa

Comment: Excelente noticia, estaremos presentes en es Webcast.

Comment: Un desarrollador... estoy tentado a gritar ¡¡que arregle los bugs!! ;P

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster lamento decepcionarte... trabajo en el equipo de /jobs, no en Q&A ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @g3rv4 ò_ó vaya... pues azota a alguien para arreglar bugs :P

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster buena idea! puedo azotar a konamiman!

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Es problema de hardware, Ya limpiaste tu cache, En mi maquina si funciona, Ya reiniciaste tu equipo, Ya desactivaste tu antivirus, Es un tema de compatibilidad con IE, Ya hablaste con tu proveedor de internet, Intenta aumentar la RAM, No estaba en los requerimientos iniciales

Comment: @jasilva ¡Me da ganas de escribir un blog tomando tu comentario!

Comment: vamos con todo el power 2.0!!!

Comment: ¿Quiénes son los del #14? ¿Son [este](https://t3chfest.uc3m.es/2017/programa/gobierno-apis/) y [este](http://baumannzone.com/)? ¿Tienen usuario en el sitio (probablemente [jBaumann](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/17540/jbaumann))?

Comment: @Mariano Sí, ellos son. :)

Comment: @JuanM De que manera se proponen los webcast? Quiero decir, si tuviese un tema muy interesante sobre el que se pudiera hablar, quien o como se proponen los webcast?

Comment: @ivanbotero Lo puedes hacer al mandarme un correo a jgarza @ stackoverflow.com

Comment: El 16 de agosto ¿Estarian los moderadores electos? Seria interesante que los conociera "personalmente" la comunidad

Comment: @jasilva Sí, los moderadores oficiales los tendremos el primero de agosto. Tengo en mente planear un webcast con los 3 para darle la oportunidad a la comunidad de conocerlos. :)

Comment: que cheeere! :D

Comment: Me gustaría *recordar* que Eferion y yo tenemos *apalabrado* un webcast sobre C++17. Me gustaría que participaran más "*Cemásmásadictos*" :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster lo hacemos este mes?? :)