# Webcasts 2018 - ¿cómo y por qué? — ¡Fechas!

Tags: discusión, webcast

[Enlaces a los Webcasts del 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337/webcasts-2017-c%C3%B3mo-y-por-qu%C3%A9-fechas)

---

Bienvenidos todos a la lista de los webcasts para el 2018.  Podrán encontrar los enlaces a los episodios aquí y también al enlace para asistir al evento en vivo.

[**Episodio 17** - *La seguridad en las APIs, desde un punto de vista developer - con Marco Antonio Sanz de CloudAPIs.com*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4uo0KG1a_g)

[**Episodio 18** - *Mujeres del Desarrollo - Paula Casiano sipac, Cristina Carrasco Angulo*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q63iat54yOU)

[**Episodio 19** - Una Discusión Sobre Firebase - jirungaray, Gastón Saillén, garnav](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPyhHdYrQGo)

¡Espero que nos puedan acompañar!

---

Los webcasts se graban en vivo y se aceptan las preguntas.  Compartiremos los enlaces de los webcasts para que puedan asistir al evento en vivo.  Si por algún motivo no pueden participar durante el evento, pueden ver la grabación en nuestro [*canal de YouTube*](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtuOuRfJHaReTPEPf0RTMVg).

Comment: ¿Y qué pasó con el episodio 19? :P

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Uuups!  Permíteme corregirlo. :D