# ¿Le damos otra temporada a los Webcasts?

Tags: discusión, webcast

Saludos estimada comunidad, conversando con algunos integrantes, ha salido la "novedad" de esta iniciativa. Tiempo atrás hemos realizado webcasts que quedaron grabados en el canal de YouTube de StackOverflow en Español y considerando que muchos estamos en periodo de "cuarentena", me gustaría saber quiénes se animarían a entrar en un conversatorio informal sobre tecnologías y cosas que suceden en SOes, la idea está para pulir y sería interesante contar con su apoyo para ello.

Lo que sí queda en claro es el horario que tendría que ser un sábado (o varios sábados) en la mañana (9am-11am) GTM -7 para los que estamos por esta franja horaria, para quienes estén en España puedan acceder 7pm-8pm y los que están por todo Latam puedan acceder durante la tarde.

¿Qué dicen? ¿Se animan?

**Actualización Mayo 13, 2020**

Se trata de compartir algún tema que consideren que conocen, todos tenemos niveles diferentes y da lo mismo si uno recién empieza o si tiene años en el tema, la clave es compartir la aventura de nuestros días con el código y experiencias que podamos tener, bugs críticos, cosas que lograron funcionar, cosas que no, éxitos y por qué no también fracasos (¿quién dice que todo siempre tiene que salir perfecto? el fracaso es parte del éxito :D), mientras exista respeto, tolerancia y buen humor con buen ánimo, el evento saldrá bien :D

Para dejar en claro el tiempo y las zonas horarias:

```
11 am en GMT -7 Hora del Pacífico tiene equivalencia en:
08 am en GMT -10 Hawaii 
12 pm en GMT -6 Costa Rica, Guatemala
01 pm en GMT -5 México City, Perú, New York, Texas
02 pm en GMT -4 Bolivia
03 pm en GMT -3 Argentina, Uruguay
07 pm en GMT +0 Londres
08 pm en GMT +1 España, Italia, Francia
09 pm en GMT +3 Rumanía, Moscú
```

Podríamos hablar un día sobre desarrollo web, otro día sobre desarrollo móvil, otro sobre bases de datos, seguridad informática, ethical hacking, meditación zen para evitar romper el teclado en momento de frustración extrema, cosas así y las que proponga la comunidad.

Quienes deseen participar, por favor, comenten, respondan indicando sobre el tema o los temas que podrían compartir y vamos viendo qué logramos realizar entre todos :D

Dato de vital importancia, las temporadas anteriores:

- [Webcasts 2016](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419/822)
- [Webcasts 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1337/822)
- [Webcasts 2018](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3087/822)
- Webcasts 2019 no se realizaron webcasts oficiales; sí hubo 1 uno no
  oficial que hice con el buen [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) donde hablamos en vivo sobre:
  [Mentalidad del buen desarrollador de software](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqzVCY1jzXQ)

Canal oficial en YouTube de StackOverflow en Español:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtuOuRfJHaReTPEPf0RTMVg

Comment: Y que es lo debemos hacer para Acceder?,

Comment: @Shassain comentar sobre los temas de tu interés y de los que podrías compartir con la comunidad :D

Comment: excelente iniciativa @fred

Comment: @fredyfx que tema se tendria que manejar

Comment: el que gusten, la idea es compartir experiencias con la comunidad :D

Comment: Me gusta la idea de retomar esta iniciativa.

Comment: Propongan temas, tecnologías, ponentes :D

Comment: Podemos hablar sobre la dictadura del clan de programadores de C Sharp impuesta en el chat de SOes y cómo la palabra con ***J*** desata la llamada *ira del moderador*, mientras se castiga con indiferencia al pobre ¿programador? que usa PHP, todo esto ante la vista impávida de los Dioses Pythónicos que observan desde el Olimpo de la Programación.

Comment: HAHAHAAAAAAAA XD!!!!!!!!!!! también, todo suma, este sitio se ha convertido en un lugar especial para muchos :D

Answer (score 7):

Muchas gracias a [@fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx) por la traducción.

---

¡Muchas gracias! Los webcasts son una importante iniciativa comunitaria para conocerse. Es genial ver que quieres organizar uno. Aunque no hablo español, me gustaría ayudar. Si crees que puedo hacer algo para que el webcast se realice, por favor házmelo saber ([envíame un correo electrónico](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile), ping me [en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal) o deja un comentario a esta respuesta).

Es una gran iniciativa! No puedo esperar a ver el próximo episodio de Stack Overflow en el webcast en español =)

Comment: hey Nicolas, thanks for your kind words! If you don't speak Spanish, no worries, we can help you out to do live translations, count with me for it :D On the other hand, what kind of topics would you like to share with us?

Comment: @fredyfx Buena pregunta. No trabajo como desarrollador durante bastante tiempo, aunque hago algunos análisis de datos en el tiempo libre. Al mismo tiempo, lo único que puedo hablar es la gestión comunitaria =)

Comment: @Nicolas hablar de la comunidad SOes desde la perspectiva de CM sería muy interesante. Futuro del sitio, iniciativas... a mí me gustaría mucho escucharte hablar de ello, pues sabes mucho y te apasiona!

Comment: That will be awesome! Quick question @NicolasChabanovsky Which timezone do you live with?

Comment: @fredyfx Zona horaria de Moscú (GMT +3)