# ¡Viene una temporada de Webcasts! Necesitamos temas y ponentes :D

Tags: discusión

[image: Live Streaming]

Buen día estimada comunidad, hace 1 mes (mayo 7) publiqué esta pregunta: [¿Le damos otra temporada a los Webcasts?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4702/822) Y tuvo buena aceptación, estoy en coordinación con [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10/nicolas-chabanovsky) para realizar esta iniciativa.

Considerando principalmente los horarios de Latino américa y Europa, serían los sábados en la mañana para Norteamérica (11am), al mismo tiempo en Centro América sería el mediodía, para Sudamérica entre 1pm y 3pm, y para Europa entre 7pm y 9pm.

**Temporada Sabatina de Stackoverflow Webcasts**

Esta "primera" temporada constará de 5 episodios, donde iniciamos el episodio 1 con el buen Nicolas y un posible invitado sorpresa :D

Básicamente la estructura de este tipo de eventos es un punto medio entre una entrevista y una conversación casual de amigos charlando sobre los temas propuestos.

La duración de los webcasts se estima en un rango de 40 minutos a 1 hora.

Fechas tentativas para el primer episodio: Junio 20, Junio 27.

Lo que necesitamos es su apoyo: propuestas de temas y potencial candidatos/as, dependiendo de la disponibilidad del (de los) candidatos(as) procedemos a agendar tema y fechas. ¿Tienen en mente a alguien que deseen escuchar? Puedes auto-proponerte para participar :D

Escriban una propuesta de tema por cada respuesta, de este modo podremos ver las votaciones de la comunidad, así mismo, dentro de cada respuesta, propongan a expositores (incluyéndose si desean participar como tal), pueden haber varios, coordinamos y ¡queda!

Muchas gracias por su atención, quedamos atentos a sus respuestas :D

Comment: queremos escuchar pikoh :p

Comment: @gbianchi hahaha creyó que podía escaparse :P

Comment: aquí los únicos que podrían escaparse son los que andan por Japón, China, salvo se despierten a media madrugada para el live :D

Comment: Alguien dijo abulafia ?

Comment: Me gustarìa realizaras algunos Webcasts, al igual Gonzalo Bianchi, ya tienen experiencia en esto.

Comment: ¿Alguna novedad con los webcasts? ¿Se hará el primero en las fechas planteadas? para el 20 o el 24 queda poco menos de 4 y 8 días respectivamente. ¿Alguno de los ponentes propuestos a confirmado algo? @Pikoh no se puede salvar. Si no lo hace, soy capaz de participar en un webcast de C# y mostrar código con las llaves en la misma línea, a modo de protesta, no sólo por no dejarse oír, sino por el régimen autocrático y dictatorial con que rige el *chat* de SOes, desde su bastión de C# y sus aplicaciones de escritorio.

Comment: En caso no haya respuesta de algún posible speaker, pasamos el webcast para el mes de julio en fechas del 11 y 18 de tal modo tener tiempo suficiente para las coordinaciones necesarias :D Por otro lado, la premisa que planeas depende de la respuesta de @Pikoh ¿y si no responde? la respuesta sería null o.o ¿tienes algún try/catch para este posible escenario? Dicho de otro modo, te apuntas para estar en el Live al margen de la respuesta de @Pikoh? (No quiero sonar presionando, faltan ponentes y de los que han sido propuestos, nadie confirma, tampoco comentan T.T)

Comment: El primer WebCast podria ser la presentacion de los nuevos, y no tan nuevos moderadores para conocerlos.

Answer (score 15):

Obviamente y dado el frustrado intento que tuvimos alla hace 1 año, podriamos proponer a

[image]

como nuestro amado y primer interlocutor, solo para escuchar su dulce voz

Comment: Falta la presentaciòn ante la sociedad de los nuevos moderadores! Sería sin duda un buen Webcast!

Comment: Apoyo totalmente la moción.

Answer (score 10):

Yo puedo participar con temas como los caminos del desarrollador/programador, errores en la carrera, ser autodidacta, manejo de estrés. Sigo abierto a sugerencias.

Comment: Yo te apoyo. Podremos ver al *fantasma* en vivo y directo. Órale wey.

Comment: Dicen que se puede manejar el estrés con una buena cerveza! :-)

Comment: Por su puesto! es buenisimo el ritual cervecero ;)

Answer (score 9):

Yo puedo hablar de C++, pero creo que a nadie le interesa C++.

[image]

Comment: Y si te dijera que sí hay gente a la que le interesa C++ ?

Comment: Me incluyo en ese grupo por cierto :D

Comment: Te diría que no participan en la etiqueta [tag:c++].

Comment: Paula es siempre bienvenida...

Comment: no solo de C++ puedes hablar de otro tema relacionado a la programacion, estoy seguro C++ es uno de los juiguetes que tienes en esa Bolsa, deben haber mas,

Comment: por cierto y conociendo tus juegos mentales... estas [postulando a sstan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18951/sstan) o estas opinando sobre si interesa o no?

Comment: @JackNavaRow desafortunadamente sstan tiene casi 2 años que no está activo en SO, pero sí, sería genial ver su regreso con un webcast

Answer (score 7):

Mis temas propuestos:

***Harry Potter  y la Piedra Maestra de Papel:***

- *[PotterLozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22851/pablo-lozano)*
- *[El Programador que nunca se debe decir su nombre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster)*

***Star Wars - La Guerra de las Serpientes:***

- *[Abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia)*
- *[FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla)*

Comment: Huele a JavaScript, C++ y Python :D

Comment: Después de la guerra de serpientes nace *Python 4.0*

Comment: @LucasDamian o seguramente crean un nuevo lenguaje de programacion y lo llamen medusa

Comment: Me quitaste mis opciones, realmente me gustaría oír a Pablo Lozano. Hace tiempo [comenté](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49902863#49902863) en el chat de SOes que mi mente le ponía la voz de un gran amigo a Pablo Lozano, por el hecho de que se parece a mi amigo en su foto de perfil. Aparte de eso, obviamente sería un honor escuchar al medallista de oro de SOes en la etiqueta Javascript. Anímate @PabloLozano.