# ¿Cuáles son las convenciones/eventos que atiende SO Español?

Tags: discusión

**Nota:** *Este es mi primer post en `Meta`, así que disculpas si éste tipo de pregunta es simplemente errónea, y porfavor no me arranquen el cuello, que bien conozco a SO.*

---

En mi país El Salvador **(Sí, ese pequeño pedazo de tierra en Centroamérica)** generalmente no hay muchas, o básicamente ninguna; pero me interesa saber a qué clase de convenciones o eventos los integrantes de Stack Overflow en Español atienden.

Es más de naturaleza informativa, tanto para mí como para los demás que puedan leer éste post **(Si es que no me lo cierran antes)** para conocer sobre a qué lugares pueden ir de viaje, o incluso, si ocurren justo en su vecindario.

Personalmente, sólo he atendido a una: **BT7 El Salvador**. Si bien no es algo de otro mundo, sirve para decirnos a nosotros (Y a cualquiera en verdad), que soñar no es suficiente, tienes que hacerlo realidad; que el éxito no llega como si fuera una gripe, tienes que salir a buscar esa gripe de éxito.

Saludos ;)

Comment: Los eventos que organiza Stack Overflow o en los que algún empleado participa activamente se listan en [Upcoming Stack Overflow events](https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events). De momento hubo uno en Uruguay y otro en Argentina.

Answer (score 7):

Rolin, tu pregunta no será cerrada, precisamente https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/ es el lugar indicado para realizar este tipo de preguntas sobre el sitio.

Los eventos principales que realiza el sitio son los [Webcasts](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419/webcasts-2016-c%C3%B3mo-y-por-qu%C3%A9-fechas)

[Webcasts 2016 - ¿cómo y por qué? -- ¡Fechas!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419/webcasts-2016-c%C3%B3mo-y-por-qu%C3%A9-fechas)

[Webcasts 2017 - ¿cómo y por qué? — ¡Fechas!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337/webcasts-2017-c%C3%B3mo-y-por-qu%C3%A9-fechas)

Todos estos WebCast se encuentran en el [canal de Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtuOuRfJHaReTPEPf0RTMVg)

De igual forma nuestro querido manager de la comunidad [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) nos alenta precisamente a [promover nuestra comunidad en diversas formas](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/07/una-receta-para-promover-nuestra-comunidad/), una de las cuales es la organización de eventos por parte de los miembros de la comunidad y en la cual puedes participar.

Estos son ejemplos de grupos que organizaron encuentros locales que fueron realizados anteriormente:

- Buenos Aires, Argentina

  - https://www.meetup.com/es/StackOverflow-en-Espanol-Buenos-Aires/
- Monterrey, México

  - https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-en-Espanol-Monterrey/

Incluso se tuvieron reuniones de la graduación del sitio en las ciudades de Madrid, España y la Ciudad de Mexico:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/21/las-celebraciones-de-nuestra-graduacion-un-resumen/

**¿Cómo puedes enterarte de los eventos?**

Bien, pues mediante los canales oficiales:

Facebook:
https://www.facebook.com/StackOverflowEnEspanol/

Twitter:
https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow

Incluso [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) mismo, en el sitio Meta.

Para eventos en los cuales se presentan empleados físicamente, se publican en :

[Próximos eventos de Stackoverflow.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events)

Comment: El autor original de la pregunta se refiere claramente a eventos de presencia física. Los eventos digitales son muy interesantes pero están fuera de tema. Creo que la respuesta sería mejor si se quitase lo que no está dentro del tema.

Answer (score 0):

Existen eventos en varias partes del mundo hispano-parlante.  Por ejemplo, yo uso el sitio de [Lanyrd.com](http://lanyrd.com/conferences/) para buscar conferencias en diferentes partes del mundo.  Allí tienen varias opciones de temas y lugares.